# async.map doesn't call cb with a nested waterfall

Tags: javascript, async.js

I have some trouble with **async**.

This is my code:

```
Main.prototype._onlyGeoLinks = function() {
  var redis = RedisClient.client
    , getKeys = function(key, cb) {
      redis.keys(key, cb);
    }
    , count = 0
  //
  cb = null;
  async.waterfall([
    function(cb) {
      async.concat([
        'events:*'
        , 'news:*:*:*:*'
        , 'deals:*'
      ], getKeys, cb);
    },
    function(keys, cb) {
      // iterate keys
      async.map(keys, function(key, cb) {
        async.waterfall([
          function(cb) {
            redis.get(key, cb);
          }, function(item, cb) {
            log.verbose(LOG_CTX, 'Parsing item.. %d', ++count);
            GeoHelper.parse(item, cb); // This are calling cb(new Error('bla'))
          }
        ], cb) // at this point, I can read err
      }, cb) // This is never called
    }
  ], function(err, items) {
    if (err) {
      log.error(LOG_CTX, err);
    } else {
      log.verbose(LOG_CTX, items);
      log.verbose(LOG_CTX, items.length);
    }
  })
}
```

*What I've tried...*

```
async.map(keys, function(key, cb) {
    async.waterfall([
      function(cb) {
        redis.get(key, cb);
      }, function(item, cb) {
        log.verbose(LOG_CTX, 'Parsing item.. %d', ++count);
        GeoHelper.parse(item, cb);
      }
    ], function(err) {
      log.error('1', err);  // This prints ERR
      cb(err);
    })
  }, function(err) {
    log.error('2', err);  // this is never called
    cb(err);
  })
```

What am I missing? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if a iterator during mapping calls cb with an error, the main cb will be called but the map will continue. This is why I didn't saw the error, output was covered with the output of valid responses.

> If iterator passes an error to this callback, the main callback (for
>   the map function) is immediately called with the error

[Async#map](https://github.com/caolan/async#map)